# Very Basic Blog - how to set an instance variable to all the posts from a specific date from a datetime attribute in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record-query

As the title says, I want to set an instanced variable equal to all the posts with the same date in a datetime attribute. I previously had two separate variables for date and time, but just recently restructured it so that it's a datetime and now I don't know how to parse through for the specific date. Please advise. Here is the relevant code:

Post Controller:

```
def index
    @datetime = DateTime.parse() rescue DateTime.now.to_date
    @posts = Post.where("(I don't know what to put in here)").order('datetime ASC')
end
```

edit: schema

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "datetime"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have timestamps

```
def index
    target_date_time = Time.now.to_datetime
    @posts = Post.where(:datetime => target_date_time.beginning_of_day..target_date_time.end_of_day).order('datetime ASC')
end
```

if you don't have timestamps always add them in the future and just put in the attribute where your date_time is stored in place of created_at.

Comment: I was assuming you were only asking about the content of the query based on your question and that @datetime in your code was reliably being set.  Where were you expecting to get that value from originally?

Comment: Ok I have edited so that target_date_time is now today.  If my responses helped you, please mark the answer as correct.  :)